# Commit and Push Container in Azure Container Group?

Tags: azure, docker, containers

My question has to do with the posture of Azure container groups. I'm comfortable working with Docker images and and deploying those in a Kubernetes environment. I'm new to Azure. I have a container running in a container group. I deployed it with a JSON template, through the web portal. I can bash into it with the Connect option in the web portal and make some changes. In a Docker environment, I would then commit those changes to an image and push that to my repository. I want to know how to do the same with a container running in a container group in Azure. I'm getting the sense that it's more like a Kubernetes environment, where the expectation is that you've already built your image to spec and now you're just deploying it and using it as-is (changes are made and committed elsewhere). However, it also seems like this should be a really basic functionality of the service Microsoft is offering here. What's the deal?

Thanks

Comment: `docker commit` is almost never a best practice: it leads to one-off images you can't reproduce.  (Think about how you might have patched the recent log4j security vulnerability in an image you created via `docker commit`.)  If you need to rebuild an image, the a better approach is to commit a change to source control and ask your CI system to build a new image from the Dockerfile.

Comment: OK.  Can you also answer the question?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A container group is a collection of containers that get scheduled on the same host machine

The containers in a container group share a lifecycle, resources, local network, and storage volumes

Azure Container Group is similar in concept to a pod in Kubernetes

In the Azure Container Group, you will be deploying the images which were already built (changes are made and committed elsewhere)

If you want to rebuild an image, you can commit the changes to your source control and build the image from there